# What are the other forms of switch statement in C?

Tags: c

I'm reading KN King's *A Modern Approach to C Programming*, 2nd edition.

It says, there are also other forms of switch statement besides general switch statement (with case keyword).
The general form of switch statement is

```
switch (exp)
{
 case constant-exp:
  statement;
  break;
 case constant-exp:
  statement;
  break;
 ...
 ...
 default:
  statement;
  break;
}
```

It also says (in Q&A) switch statement can have form with no case keyword for example.
I tried running an example with no case keyword, but it doesn't run (under std=-c99).

So, I wanted to know what are the other forms of switch statement that are valid in Standard C99.

**EDIT: Cited fro BOOK**

In it's most common form, the switch statement has the form

```
switch ( expression ) {
case constant-expression : statements
...
case constant-expression : statements
default : statements
}
```

**Q&A**

**Q: The template given for the switch statement described it as the "most common form." Are there other forms?

A**: The switch statement is a bit more general than described in this chapter, although the description given here is general enough for virtually all programs.
For example, a **switch statement can contain labels that aren't preceded by the word case**, which leads to amusing (?) trap. Suppose that we accidentally missell the word default:

```
switch(...) {
...
defualt:  ...
}
```

The compiler may not detect the error, since it assumes that *defualt* is an ordinary label.

Comment: It's possible that the author meant you could have one with only a `default` keyword, but I can't imagine a human would ever program that.  (I don't see why the compiler wouldn't accept it, and some code-generation programs might produce that code.)  There's also the completely acceptable case of not having a `break` statement after some or all `case`/`default` keywords.

Comment: I am waiting to see whether [Duff’s device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) will appear in an answer.

Comment: I don't think he meant to say so. It's clearly mentioned that using a break statement is not mandatory, without break statements following matched case will all be executed.
Is it valid to write case labels with no case keyword like
    switch(var)
    {
     1:
     break;
     2:
     break;
     default:
     }

It's said if we write lables like above, a typo will not cause error. I mean, if you mistakely type defualt instead of default, and if no matching case found, nothing will be executed neither an error will occur. It's simply treated as an ordinary lable, it says.

Comment: Regarding `defualt:  ...`, just try it.  If your compiler is decent, it will throw an error.  Regarding a rarely used, but useful expression, see my post below (too long to put here)

Answer (score 7):

The syntax of a `switch` statement is:

```
switch ( expression ) statement
```

where the `statement` portion is typically a block (compound statement) containing labeled statements of the form:

```
case constant-expression : statement
```

or

```
default : statement
```

A `switch` statement isn't *required* to contain `case` or `default` labels, but there's no point in using a `switch` if you're not going to have one or more such labels.  For example, this:

```
switch (42);
```

is a perfectly legal `switch` statement (the controlled statement is the null statement `;`), but it's also perfectly useless.

I suspect you've misunderstood what the book says.

Your quote from the book says:

> For example, a switch statement can contain labels that aren't
>   preceded by the word case, which leads to amusing (?) trap. Suppose
>   that we accidentally mispsell the word default:
>   `switch(...) { ... defualt: ... }`

The contents of a `switch` statement *should* be a block containing a sequence of `case` and `default` labels, each one ending either with a `break` or with a comment indicating that the control flow falls through to the next case. The point is that the language doesn't require this; the way it specifies the syntax gives you a lot of freedom (perhaps too much!). The only restriction is that `case` and `default` labels cannot appear outside a `switch` statement.

For example, suppose you accidentally write:

```
enum blah { foo, bar, baz };

switch (expr) {
    case foo:
        /* ... */
        break;
    bar:           /* forgot the `case` keyword */
        /* ... */
        break;
    defualt:       /* misspelled "default" */
        /* ... */
        break;
}
```

Neither `bar:` nor `defualt:` was what was intended -- but they're both perfectly legal. They're ordinary labels, the kind that can be the target of a `goto` statement. Since there is no `goto` targeting either label, the corresponding chunks of code will never be executed. If `expr` is equal to `foo`, it will jump to the `case foo:`; for any other value, it will jump to the end of the `switch` statement.

And because they're perfectly legal, a compiler won't necessarily warn you about the error.

This is a common phenomenon in C. The grammar is so "dense" that a seemingly minor typo can easily give you something that's syntactically valid, but whose behavior is entirely different from what you intended.

Crank up the warning levels on your compiler, and pay attention to all the warnings you see. And be careful; the responsibility for writing your code correctly is ultimately yours. The compiler can help, but it can't catch all errors.

Comment: Okay, I just added what the book really says.
I hope you'll understand what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

***Regarding your observation***:  *there are also other forms of switch statement besides general switch statement (with case keyword)*  Generally, the switch statement is very well documented, but there are a few interesting variations in the way the case statements are used...

***Although nothing Earth shaking here***,  It may be useful to note: ***[Sun (a flavor of unix)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7598/giphi/index.html)*** and  ***[GNU C compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges)*** have an extension that provides ***case ranges***  for use with the `switch()` statement.  So, for example, ***rather than using the classic syntax***:

```
:
case 'A':
case 'B':
:
case 'Z':  
//do something here.
break;
```

and so on...

A ***case range*** syntax can be used to delineate the conditions:

```
switch(input)  {

    case 'A' ... 'Z':
       printf("Upper case letter detected");
       break;
    case 'a' ... 'z':
       printf("Lower case letter has been detected");
       break;
};
```

***Important Note:***, case ranges are not part of the C standard (C99 or C11) rather ***only an extension*** of the environments I have mentioned, and in no way should be considered portable.  Case ranges are gaining in popularity (or at least in interest) and may be included as part of the ***[C standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)*** at some point, but not yet (AFAIK).

Comment: +1 for mentioning case ranges. I'd definitely vote for them to become part of the standard ... along with removing the restriction of case labels being constant expressions...

Answer (score 1):

The go-to source for C-99 is the [C-99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), though of course C-99 has been replaced by C11.  The switch statement is on page 134 of the C-99 standard.  They give an example of what is probably the most non-general switch statement you can have:

```
EXAMPLE In the artiﬁcial program fragment
switch (expr)
{
    int i = 4;
    f(i);
case 0:
    i=17;
    /* falls through into default code */
default:
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

> the object whose identiﬁer is i exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never
>   initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the printf function will
>   access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to the function f cannot be reached.

Note the ways that this is not "standard" (and is generally bad code).

- You have code that is not under any `case` or `default` label.  In fact, nothing but identifier declarations seems to be acknowledged, so that `i` is a valid variable within the scope of the switch statement, but setting it or calling functions without a `case` or `default` label causes errors.
- What I think the author wanted you to notice was that it's valid to not have a `break` under each label.  In this example, `case 0` falls through to the `default` label, but if there were other `case` labels beneath `case 0`, it would go through each one until you did hit a break statement.

  - For that matter, though not in this example, you can put the `default` label first.  Again, if you don't put a break after it, you'll execute code under any following labels.

As I mentioned in my comment, you could just have a `default` label if you want, but that effectively renders the switch statement meaningless:

```
switch (exp)
{
default:
    statement;
}
```

that's effectively equivalent to `{ statement; }`.

Incidentally, you can do some clever (but confusing) tricks with avoiding break statements, e.g. this is a valid (though less efficient than `c - '0'`) way to convert a digit character `c` to an integer:

```
int i = 0;
switch (c) {
case '9': ++i;
case '8': ++i;
case '7': ++i;
case '6': ++i;
case '5': ++i;
case '4': ++i;
case '3': ++i;
case '2': ++i;
case '1': ++i;
case '0':
default:
}
```

Comment: Okay, read yourself what the book really says.
I added it in my question.
That's certainly not what I'm looking for.

Comment: To understand the `label` issue, look back 3 pages on the standard.  Page 131 talks about labelled statements (typically used with `goto`, which is anathema to most C programmers), of which `case` and `default` are special cases.  Technically, what the author is talking about with "not needing `case` and `default`" isn't specific to `switch` statements, but to all C statements, and in that way is misleading.  Remember, the published standard is always the answer, not any book written by anyone else.

Comment: So what does it mean when he says _a switch statement can contain labels that aren't preceded by the word case_ ?
The book is C99 compliant.

Comment: It means that any statement in C can contain a label.  It's usually used for `goto` statements, though it could be used simply decoratively as a way of making code blocks more clear.  As far as the spec shows, I don't think the labels would be acknowledged by the `switch` functionality.  `switch` looks for `case` and `default` and operates on that.  But it's not illegal to have other labels inside your switch block, and `goto` them.  Heck, you can even `goto` them from outside of the switch block.  But that's how labels and `goto` work, not how `switch` specifically works.

Comment: It seems that the author was telling you: "The specification is fairly loose.  Lots of things are legal."  But they're not necessarily useful.  While I have seen occasional uses for "case fall-throughs", I've never seen anyone use a label other than `case` and `default` inside a switch statement.  The biggest takeaway from the cited text is "Be careful when typing case or default, because typos won't necessarily cause an error."  That said, it's likely it'll cause a warning.

Comment: Yeah.
I'm just wondering if there are any other forms for switch statement as the author says.

Comment: Sorry, at this point, my only response is: I've given you some other significant forms (case fall-throughs, default in a different order, default only), and the author isn't listing specific "other forms of the switch statement" - just very obscure uses of the rest of the way C works.  The best you can do is read the spec for yourself, or contact the author to find out what he was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki describes how the switch statement defined as below considering different coding languages,

In most languages, a switch statement is defined across many individual lines using one or two keywords. A typical syntax is:

```
1. The first line contains the basic keyword, usually switch, case or select, 
   followed by an expression which is often referred to as the control expression
   or control variable of the switch statement.

2. Subsequent lines define the actual cases (the values) with corresponding 
   sequences of statements that should be executed when a match occurs.
```

Each alternative begins with the particular value, or list of values, that the control variable may match and which will cause the control to go to the corresponding sequence of statements. The value (or list/range of values) is usually separated from the corresponding statement sequence by a colon or an implication arrow. In many languages, every case must also be preceded by a keyword such as case or when. An optional default case is typically also allowed, specified by a default or else keyword; this is executed when none of the other cases matches the control expression.

Comment: I already read that. Thank you anyway.
Please read the edit in my question, and you'll understand what I'm asking for.